# Common length of strings in java

Tags: java, regex, string

In this java program everything works fine but at the last i have to get the number of words matched in length of character but i cant how to get it?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String s1 = "Enter the name 1:";
System.out.println(s1);
s1 = input.next();

String s2 = "Enter the name 2:";
System.out.println(s2);
s2 = input.next();

if (s1.equals(s2)) {
    System.out.println("They match");
} else {
    System.out.println("They dont match");
}

char[] c = s1.toCharArray();
char[] d = s2.toCharArray();

for (char i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (char j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
        if (c[i] == d[j]) {
            System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + c[i]);
        }

    }
}
System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + c.length);
```

Comment: indents are your best friend. Or they should be.

Comment: You're saying that you "have to get the number of words matched in length of character", but your code attempts to count the number of characters two string have in common, which is not quite the same thing. Make up your mind!

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter

```
int counter = 0 ;
for (char i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (char j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
        if (c[i] == d[j]) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + c[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + counter);
```

Comment: This will give 9 for input `aaa` and `aaa`, which I don't think is the intended meaning of OP

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] c = s1.toCharArray();
char[] d = s2.toCharArray();
int count = 0;
for (char i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (char j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
        if (c[i] == d[j]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

}

System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + count);
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

You need to count the number of matches in your loop, then after looping display the number of letters that are in both arrays.

Comment: This will give 9 for input aaa and aaa, which I don't think is the intended meaning of OP

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to get the number of common characters between two strings, then one approach is to convert both strings to character sets and do set intersection between the two sets and get its size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of times a character in s1 also appears in s2:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
  if (s2.indexOf(s1.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
    counter++;
  }
}
System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + counter);
```

If instead you want the number of distinct characters shared by s1 and s2:

```
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
    set.add(s1.charAt(i));
}
for (int j=0; j<s2.length(); j++) {
  if (set.contains(s2.charAt(j))) {
    counter++;
  }
}
System.out.println("The number of letters matched are :" + counter);
```